# Clearing site cache after a site content update

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I've just rolled out a major update to my work site.

Some of the resources are still being called from cached versions, such as the style sheets and javascript files. Some visitors to the site will still see the old resources.

Is there a htaccess command to force all assests to re-cache from a set date

Answer (score 0):

What I do instead of messing with my .htaccess rules every time I do an update, is I append the name of the styles and js files I changed with a random number or the date/time I changed it.

That way the browser see's it as a new file, loads it and caches the new version.

For example in your tag, add a version query string.

`style.css?version=3.2` or use a hash `style.css?version=V6CbUlTe7M94ol8`

This can be done with your JS files too. Much easier and better to do then messing with your Apache config. Anytime you make an update just change the version and it will be re-cached for all.

> FYI, StackOverflow uses the same technique. Look at the source code
>   for this page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=dc5a5d7ef830">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)>
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Honestly that's not the best way to handle that by changing your Apache settings every time. The method I told is even used my major sites including StackOverflow and its much easier to maintain. The big companies must know a thing or two. :)

Comment: While you might not see it as he best way, it does work. Ideally I'd like to add version control to each resource, but he templates that are currently in place don't allow this. Do you have any examples of why the above is not a great method?

Comment: Yes of course it works. But you must not be running a critical site or a production site because, typically you don't want to muck around with your Apache config on a live site just to expire cache. That's not safe at all. If you fat finger something or use a bad parameter it can bring your site down. For some sites, even seconds being down matters. Simply changing the file name is less risky and a better practice to get the browser to recache it. Look at Facebook's source. They frequently change the CSS file names using hashes(same concept) or random strings.